# Why IEEEtran is blurry with XeLaTeX but not with PDFLaTeX, and how to fix it?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf, rendering

The question is pretty simple.

Compiling this code with PDFLaTeX

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

gives me back

[image]

whereas compiling the same code with XeLaTeX gives me back

[image]

I'm curious why this happens, but more importantly, I'd like to know:
*How can I force XeLaTeX to avoid doing whatever it does that makes its output render differently like this from the PDFLaTeX output?*

In case it matters, I'm running this on MiKTeX 2.9 (Windows).

Comment: I see no difference between the two methods on my system: MikTeX 2.9 x64. pdflatex v3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 and XeTeX v3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3

Comment: @PaulGessler: That's actually exactly the same version I have (even the 64-bit-ness is the same.) What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: I use SumatraPDF. But the result is the same in Adobe Reader and Google Chrome.

Comment: @PaulGessler: That's bizarre. Which one of my screenshots does your XeLaTeX output look like?

Comment: The first (your pdflatex output).

Comment: @PaulGessler: That's really bizarre. When I try viewing mine in Chrome, I still see a difference between the [PDFLaTeX output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FLlfp.png) and the [XeTeX output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6NDEs.png)... any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15733/discussion-between-paul-gessler-and-mehrdad).

Comment: @PaulGessler: It seems like this issue comes up when the default paper format is changed from A4 to letterPaper in the MiKTeX settings dialog. I would ask you to confirm, but it might mess up your installation too (!) would you like to give it a try? Or could you maybe take a look and let me know if your default is letter or A4?

Comment: My default is letter paper. Based on this and our discussion in the chat, it seems likely that your installation is either not complete or not functioning properly. I've not seen anything like this happen before.

Comment: @PaulGessler: That's weird, because I've reinstalled it pretty much from scratch every time, and the packages are intact, and the behavior is consistent: I tell it the default should be letter in the installation -- and it indeed is -- but then the Settings dialog still says it's A4 (A4size). But when I change that to Letter (letterSize), it says it needs to recreate the format files, and when I say OK that's when I see the problem. This does *not* happen if I merely tell it to recreate the format files though, I really need to switch A4 to letter. And switching it back doesn't fix it either.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Actually, this even happens if I *don't* tell it to recreate the format files. Merely changing the paper type causes this issue.

Comment: @Mehrdad were you able to find out the source of the problem?

Comment: @doed: See the answer I posted myself below, that's all the information I have though.

Comment: Mehrdad thanks. I have exactly the same problem than yours. Or to be exact. Just like @PaulGessler's. I followed the discussion you both had, and hoping to see a solution...

Comment: @doed: I see. Did removing the file not work for you?

Comment: @Mehrdad Nope. Made no difference. And I'm not running Windows.

Comment: @doed: Oh I see... yeah sorry. :( I'd assume it's a similar problem but I'm not sure what to suggest. If you can find some way to *not* trigger it (in my case, changing the paper size is what triggered it) then you can try finding the difference between the files in the two cases to see what changed, which is what I tried. Not sure what else you can try though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea *why* this happens, but it seems like the mere *presence* of the file

```
C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfmx.cfg
```

causes this issue, even if the file is empty.

Removing the file seems to fix the problem.

Comment: In TeX Live there *is* a `dvipdfmx.cfg` file, which is very important. Probably the (empty?) file in `dvipdfm/config` is something spurious from older versions of the `dvipdfm` software.

Comment: @egreg: It's not "left over", it's generated. See my comment thread under the question itself, the file gets generated when I change the paper size, and it only has 1 non-commented line inside it, but deleting the contents changes nothing.